# Perl ARGV value in scalar context

Tags: perl, diamond-operator, scalar-context

Given the following Perl script:

```
# USAGE: ./flurp -x -vf file1 file2 file3 file4

# e.
$a = shift;
$b = shift;
$c = shift;
@d = <>;

# ei.  value of $b = -vf
# eii. value of @d = content of file2, file3, file4

print "$b\n";
print "@d\n";
print "$ARGV\n";
```

This is the output:

```
-vf
{contents of file2, file3, file4}
file4
```

I am puzzled by the output of `print "$ARGV\n"`. If I try to do `print "$ARGV[-1]\n"`, an empty line is printed out to STDOUT. If I directly reference `$ARG[2]`, I get an empty line as well.

Why is the script printing `file4` when `$ARGV` is used?

As a counter-example, I tried `print "$d\n"`, expecting to get the last line of `file4`. Instead of the expected output I got an empty line. How does `$ARGV` work?

Comment: `$ARGV` and `@ARGV` are not the same thing!

Comment: I thought that `@LIST` and `$LIST` referred to the same variable since `$LIST[0]` is the first index of `@LIST`. Perl is a confusing beast.

Comment: `$ARGV[n]` is accessing `@ARGV`. `$ARGV` is a separate variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In answer to your specific question: *"How does $ARGV work?"*

> $ARGV Contains the name of the current file when reading from <> .

from *[Variables related to filehandles](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles)* in the Perl docs.

Although at the point you print `$ARGV` you've finished reading from file4, the variable still holds the name of the file.